# "elif" in gcc: #elif with no expression error

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
#define RELEASE_TEST

#if RELEASE
  // code1
#elif RELEASE_TEST
  // code2
#else
  // code3
#endif
```

gcc claims about `#elif`: "error: #elif with no expression".

I do not understand this error, because I provide "RELEASE_TEST" expression to "elif".

How to make my code working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RELEASE_TEST is defined, but with no value, so this expands to just `#elif`, which isn't valid.

You could either use `#elif defined(RELEASE_TEST)` to test if it's defined at all, or `#define RELEASE_TEST 1`, which would cause that line to expand to `#elif 1`.